# gitlab runner unable to download Artifacts Missing .. Artifacts downloading is disabled

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

Unable to download artifacts on one or two specific environment, I couldn't find any other information about this error on Internet.

```
Missing .. Artifacts downloading is disabled.
```

[Missing .. Artifacts downloading is disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NixYR.png)

Here is gitlab runner debug log:

```
Checking for jobs... nothing                        runner=e45b23a6
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
Checking for jobs... received                       job=424843 repo_url=https://git.mail.netease.com/qiye_esc/QiyeRoot.git runner=e45b23a6
Failed to requeue the runner:                       builds=1 runner=e45b23a6
Running with gitlab-runner 11.3.1~beta.4.g0aa5179e (0aa5179e)  job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
  on bj-test-224.205 e45b23a6                       job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Shell configuration: environment: []
dockercommand:
- sh
- -c
- "if [ -x /usr/local/bin/bash ]; then\n\texec /usr/local/bin/bash --login\nelif [
  -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then\n\texec /usr/bin/bash --login\nelif [ -x /bin/bash ]; then\n\texec
  /bin/bash --login\nelif [ -x /usr/local/bin/sh ]; then\n\texec /usr/local/bin/sh
  --login\nelif [ -x /usr/bin/sh ]; then\n\texec /usr/bin/sh --login\nelif [ -x /bin/sh
  ]; then\n\texec /bin/sh --login\nelif [ -x /busybox/sh ]; then\n\texec /busybox/sh
  --login\nelse\n\techo shell not found\n\texit 1\nfi\n\n"
command: bash
arguments:
- --login
passfile: false
extension: ""
  job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Using Shell executor...                             job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Waiting for signals...                              job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Executing build stage                               build_stage=prepare_script job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Executing build stage                               build_stage=get_sources job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=1
Executing build stage                               build_stage=restore_cache job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Executing build stage                               build_stage=download_artifacts job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Executing build stage                               build_stage=build_script job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Executing build stage                               build_stage=after_script job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Executing build stage                               build_stage=archive_cache job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Executing build stage                               build_stage=upload_artifacts_on_success job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Job succeeded                                       job=424843 project=11376 runner=e45b23a6
Appending trace to coordinator... ok                code=202 job=424843 job-log=0-9395 job-status=running runner=e45b23a6 sent-log=0-9394 status=202 Accepted
Submitting job to coordinator... ok                 code=200 job=424843 job-status= runner=e45b23a6
Checking for jobs... nothing                        runner=e45b23a6
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
Checking for jobs... nothing                        runner=e45b23a6
```

Answer (score 0):

It was all because I had compressed gitlab-runner binary file with [upx](https://upx.github.io/)